# How to handle results output without cluttering code?

Tags: design-patterns, python

My Python project performs a complex set of operations, and it's important to make clear which operations it uses and in what order. Therefore, it has a `main` method that reads like an overview of the project, with the implementation of `operation`s outside the `main` method.:

```
class Program:
    def main(self): <--- This should be easy to read
        res1 = self.operation1()
        res2 = self.operation2(res1)
        if cond(res2):
            res3 = self.operation3(res2)
        .......
```

I also need to output many graphs based on the operations' results - both intermediary and final. This is mostly internal, for deubgging purposes. Since the graphs at later stages depend on the results of previous stages, I needed some container to hold the results over the code run. However, adding the output handling to the `main` module really cluttered it.
As a solution, I've wrapped the instance methods in the `Program` class with decorators, where the decoratos are implemented in an `output` module. Here's how it looks:

```
----- main.py -------
class Program:
    @main_wrap
    def main(self):
        .......

    @wrap1
    def operation1(self):
        .......
        return res


----- output.py -------
def main_wrap(main):
    def inner(self):
        self.res_container = [] # <-- creating instance variable outside __init__
        main(self, *args, **kwargs)
        output_final_results(self.res_container)
    return inner

def wrap1(func1):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = func1(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.res_container.append(res)
        output_intermediary_results(res)
    return inner
```

This approach feels very hack-y. I'd appreciate if you could comment or suggest a better solution that ensures both readability of the `main` method and proper code writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you use dependency injection patterns for this and factor out the recording logic to its own class(es).

```py
class Program:
    def __init__(self, recorder):
        self._recorder = recorder
    def operation1(self):
        .......
        self._recorder.log(res)
        return res

    ....
```

Then you can define two classes for recording

```py
class NoOpRecorder:
   def log(self, *args):
       pass
```

```py
class DebugRecorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self._results = []
    def log(self, *args):
        self._results.append(args)
```

So when running your program you can decide

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if debug_run:
        recorder = DebugRecorder()
    else:
        recorder = NoOpRecorder()

    Program(recorder)
```

Side note: using Dependency Injection (DI), your `Program` class turns into the 'aggregate root'.

Comment: I favour this solution. It makes it more explicit what's going on than in the decorated version (which reminds me a bit of AOP)

Comment: Aggregate root is typically associated with Domain Driven Design. You might be thinking of **composition root** instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is really that complicated, maybe it's worth reifying the results into their own (probably immutable) object?

Your `main()` could then be for gathering the results to pass to the Result constructor:

```
class Result:
    ...

class Program:
    def main(self):
        res1 = self.operation1()
        res2 = self.operation2(res1)
        if cond(res2):
            res3 = self.operation3(res2)
        return Result(res1, res2, res3 or None)
```

It might also allow for some of the operations/computations to be a bit more 'lazy' and only get done if they're called.